# Валидация формы ajax + php

Tags: php, ajax, form, валидация

ajax отправляет данные формы php скрипту, который их обрабатывает. Знаю, что при успешной обработке в ajax'e вызывается `success`. Например `success: function(){
$("#report").text('Спасибо! Вы успешно зарегистрированы');}`. А каким образом можно вывести на форму ошибку на пример "Такой пользователь уже зарегистирован"? Т.е. какие действия нужно выполнить чтобы передать с php в ajax разного вида ошибки и чем их отлавливать? Я так понимаю этим занимается `error:`? В общем как сделать корректную динамическую валидацию?

Comment: Этим не error занимается, error сработает если ошибка самого запроса случится, а существование пользователя вы сами должны проверять в своём php файле и давать ответ в зависимости от результата

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На серверной стороне добавляйте ошибки в объект ответа с ключом 'errors'

```
$response['errors'][] = 'Error...';
return json_encode($response);
```

на клиентской стороне:

```
success: function(data) {
// data - полученные от сервера данные
    if (data.errors.length > 0) {
        // вывод ошибок
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как и написал **Вадим Лешкевич**  вам нужна на php обработать все эти исключения и отдавать валидный ответ аяксу где в свою очередь на js вы должны вывести эти ошибки в читабельную для пользователя форму

Comment: Ок, а каким образом отдать аяксу исключения и как поймать их в самом аяксе? Почему-то не могу найти внятные примеры.

Comment: вы можете отдать массив значений напрмер по результату работы кода на php вы можете вернуть такой массив return $result;
где $result=Array(error=>true, pustoe_znachenie_poly_name=>true ) ;

и соответственно на стороне клиента в success:function(data){} в переменной data будет находиться наш массив $result а дальше разбираете его  и на основе данных делаете необходимые дествия

Comment: P. Fateev написал чуть более подробно